# Ignoring viewport settings on desktop browsers (how?)

Tags: mobile, viewport

How do I get desktop browsers to ignore the viewport settings I set for mobile devices? If I resize my browser window down, it puts into place those changes that I intended only for cell phones.

The page I have is readable on desktop browsers and iPads, so I'd like to create new CSS for just mobiles. For example a Nexus 4 phone screen is 768 x 1280 pixels, on par with iPads and desktop browsers, but renders everything much smaller, so I've created a different layout, I just need certain devices to ignore it.

I'm new to responsive design so I apologize for the beginner's nature of my question, I have tried to search for answers on my own. Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back in the olden days (2001), when CSS was supported very unevenly by the most popular browsers, this sort of problem was handled with browser detection. If the browser is a desktop version, you don't use the viewport tag.

Microsoft, whose IE was one of the major causes of pain back then, urges a slightly different method: detecting for browser features.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh475813.aspx

As a user, I'm having a problem with tumblr.com, which forces a viewport value of "960" on everything, making their website look terrible on my 1440x900 monitor.

I assumed all websites still used browser detection to deal with variances in CSS and HTML support. It seems they do not.